# .net 8 maui blazor hybrid android app how to open the camera and capture images from the app :

Tags: android, android-camera, .net-8.0, maui-blazor

```
@page "/scan"


//this button is the button where the user use to open the page where he can use the camera and capture images 
            <button class="text-center camera-button p-3 px-5 text-white"  >
                Scan
            </button>
```

what i want is to when the user press the scan button will opened the camera screen appears and the user can capture images using it to make another traitement on the image

i don`t have any resources  about how  i can use the camera of .net 8 maui blazor hybrid

Answer (score 1):

At first, please add the camera permission in the AndroidManiest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

And then, require the camera permission at runtime:

```
await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
//run the code at app initialization or before you open camera
```

And then in the razor page:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private async void IncrementCount()
    {
        FileResult photo;
        if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android || DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
        }
        if (photo == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            var dotnetImageStream = new DotNetStreamReference(stream);
            // this is the image stream
            // do what you want here
        }
    }    
}
```